# How to flush the nft flowtable hash of active connections?

Tags: linux, firewall

I have flowtable offloading working just perfect on my router. Sometimes I want to block some ongoing traffic, being handled via the flowtable. If I add a new blocking rule to the regular routing processing, it has no effect to the active offloaded connections. Therefore after I added some new rule, I would like to flush the hash of the flowtable to make it rebuilt again. But how? I have not found any way with nft command to emtpy the offloaded connections.
I could destroy the flowtable and re-create, but is there no nicer way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offloaded traffic is still associated with a *conntrack* entry with the property `[OFFLOAD]` (offloaded entries have a default 30s inactivity timeout and revert to non-offloaded conntrack entries without traffic seen for this time, until they get the chance (traffic) to be offloaded again). To remove the flowtable entry, remove the conntrack entry, using `conntrack -D`.

**Update**: this feature has been made available with this [commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=9b7c68b3911aef84afa4cbfc31bce20f10570d51):

> netfilter: ctnetlink: Support offloaded conntrack entry deletion
>
> Currently, offloaded conntrack entries (flows) can only be deleted
> after they are removed from offload, which is either by timeout, tcp
> state change or tc ct rule deletion. **This can cause issues for users
> wishing to manually delete or flush existing entries.**

and requires kernel 6.4 or a recent enough [LTS 6.1.x](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-6.1.y&id=2cd02ae656547f0bf47ba2b957de6a923fb41010) (~ >= 6.1.32) where it has been backported with reference example in commit:

> ```
> Example usage:
>  # Delete all offloaded (and non offloaded) conntrack entries
>  # whose source address is 1.2.3.4
>  $ conntrack -D -s 1.2.3.4
>  # Delete all entries
>  $ conntrack -F
> ```

Following LTS kernels also have the commit, make sure the a recent enough is in use: [4.19](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-4.19.y&id=b48f6963d723430dbe4cde7b756e5cfb54d365e2), [5.4](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-5.4.y&id=ec14c6e0a2e56acff04e63ee2a788cd25b9ee920), [5.10](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-5.10.y&id=468bebc426ba19f285ea4d9d9135c7584d123e20), [5.15](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-5.15.y&id=e226893c935fd4aeaff21cf1af13927bf684e669).

On an older kernel, trying to delete such *conntrack* entry will return EBUSY (as can be seen with this error removed in the commit).

The simplest to remove all and only `[OFFLOAD]` entries is:

```
conntrack -D --status OFFLOAD
```

or for *hardware* offload (not tested) that would be:

```
conntrack -D --status HW_OFFLOAD
```

But this isn't completely reliable since a flow could have reverted to non-OFFLOAD status at the wrong time, so should better not be part of the removal filter. Using additional properties of the *conntrack* entries (as seen with `conntrack -L ...`) to remove such entry should be preferred, such as protocol, source address, port etc.

So a tool like *fail2ban* which would add an entry to a set blacklist working before the usual ESTABLISHED stateful rule might have to provide the 5-uple (to remove a single flow) or just the source address (to remove all related flows for this address). For example to block (original) source 192.0.2.11 currently (or not) with status OFFLOAD, in addition to updating a set used by a drop rule, one can run (with no special care about the OFFLOAD status):

```
conntrack -D -s 192.0.2.11
```

Comment: Unfortunately deleting does not work that way:

`# conntrack -D --status OFFLOAD
conntrack v1.4.8 (conntrack-tools): Operation failed: Resource busy`

Comment: Found the commit allowing this: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=9b7c68b3911aef84afa4cbfc31bce20f10570d51  . Requires kernel 6.4

Comment: @xevior added the kernel requirements in the answer( 6.1 LTS is good enough)

Comment: @xevior all non-EOL LTS kernels have the same change (all links added). So make sure your kernel is up to date.